# What is the function to convert dataframe to code?

Tags: r

I for the life of me can neither remember nor find the function that can convert a dataframe in your environment to code that writes a dataframe i.e. for posting online or sharing.

Can anyone help?

Comment: use `dput()`, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example An alternative way is show the definition of the dataframe: `df <- data.frame(...)`

Comment: dput, that's the one, thank you